I am creating apis in next.js using mongoose and mongodb. When I am trying to create a document with an object, it is not getting created
This is my model for Quiz:
import mongoose, { Schema } from "mongoose";

const optionsSchema = new Schema({
  option1: String,
  option2: String,
});

const quizSchema = new Schema(
  {
    question: { type: String, required: true },
    answer: { type: String, required: true },
    options: optionsSchema,
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

const Quiz = mongoose.models.Quiz || mongoose.model("Quiz", quizSchema);
export default Quiz;

This is the /api/quiz/route.js
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { connectToDB } from "../../utils/connectDB";
import Quiz from "../../models/quiz";

export async function POST(request) {
  const { question, answer, options } = await request.json();
  console.log({ question, answer, options });
  await connectToDB();
  await Quiz.create({ question, answer, options });
  return NextResponse.json({ message: "Quiz Created" }, { status: 201 });
}

export async function GET() {
  await connectToDB();
  const quiz = await Quiz.find();
  return NextResponse.json({ quiz });
}


But the inserted document in my collection doesn't have options field:

What am I doing wrong? I am new to mongodb and mongoose so Please bare with me if its a silly mistake

If you added optionsSchema after your project was up and running just try restarting your server.
